# Сокеты и учетные записи на виртуальной машине

Tags: java, сокет, клиент-сервер, virtual

У меня есть виртуальная машина. На ней я запустил сервер, которому задал порт. И на этой же виртуальной машине запустил клиент где указал ip этой виртуальной машины, а также порт сервера. При подключении выдаётся ошибка. Я думаю, что это происходит из-за того, что у виртуальной машины есть учетная запись под паролем. В результате я хочу проверить работу сервер-клиент через интернет, а не только по локальной сети. Помогите люди добрые. С локальной сеть - 127.0.0.1 все проходит гладко.

Comment: учетная запись здесь вообще не при чем. на каком адресе поднимается сокет?

Comment: Статический адрес

Comment: вы можете сам адрес написать?

Comment: 195.91.142.18:7777

Comment: `netstat -an | grep 7777` выдает строку с указанным ip?

Comment: @Etki а разве виртуальная машина у него Linux? Или Вы думаете у него VPS/VDS? Человек понятия о таком ни о чем не имеет. У него вин и виртуалбокс. А Вы ему grep...